# Solving math with integers larger than any available integer data type

Tags: string, algorithm, math, c++14, largenumber

In some programming competitions where the numbers are larger than any available integer data type, we often use strings instead.

Question 1:
Given these large numbers, how to calculate **e** and **f** in the below expression?

**(a/b) + (c/d) = e/f**

note: **GCD(e,f) = 1**, i.e. they must be in minimised form. For example **{e,f} = {1,2}** rather than **{2,4}**.
Also, all **a,b,c,d** are large numbers known to us.

Question 2:
Can someone also suggest a way to find GCD of two big numbers (bigger than any available integer type)?

Comment: How large are the numbers?

Comment: larger than long long int

Comment: Are you allowed to use Java or Python? It seems pretty uncommon to ask people to implement big integers in CP. Anyway do you know how larger are the numbers from long long  int?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using full bytes or words rather than strings.

It is relatively easy to think in base 256 instead of base 10 and a lot more efficient for the processor to not do multiplication and division by 10 all the time. Ideally, choose a word size that is half the processor's natural word size, as that makes carry easy to implement. Of course thinking in base 64K or 4G is slightly more complex, but even better than base 256.

The only downside is generating the initial big numbers from the ascii input, which you get for free in base 10. Using a larger word size you can make this more efficient by processing a number of digits initially into a single word (eg 9 digits at a time into 4G), then performing a long multiply of that single word into the correct offset in your large integer format.

A compromise might be to run your engine in base 1 billion: This will still be 9 or 81 times more efficient than using base 10!

The simplest way to solve this equation is to multiply a/b * d/d and c/d * b/b so they both have the common denominator b*d.

I think you will then need to prime factorise your big numbers e and f to find any common factors. Remember to search again for the same factor squared.

Of course, that means you have to write a prime generating sieve. You only need to generate factors up to the square root, or half the digits of the min value of e and f.

You could prime factorise b and d to get a lower initial denominator, but you will need to do it again anyway after the addition.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way to solve this is to separate the problem:

1. Process the input numbers as an array of characters (ie. `std::string`)
2. Make a class where each object can store an `std::list` (or similar) that represents one of the large numbers, and can do the needed arithmetic with your data
3. You can then solve your problems normally, without having to worry about your large inputs causing overflow.

[Here's a webpage that explains how you can have such an arithmetic class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-two-large-numbers/) (with sample code in C++ showing addition).

Once you have such an *arithmetic* class, you no longer need to worry about how to store the data or any overflow.

I get the impression that you already know how to find the GCD when you don't have overflow issues, but just in case, [here's an explanation of finding the GCD](http://www.trytoprogram.com/cpp-examples/cplusplus-program-to-find-gcd-hcf/) (with C++ sample code).

As for the specific math problem:

```
// given formula: a/b + c/d = e/f
// = ( ( a*d + b*c ) / ( b*d ) )

// Define some variables here to save on copying
// (I assume that your class that holds the
//   large numbers is called "ARITHMETIC")
ARITHMETIC numerator = a*d + b*c;
ARITHMETIC denominator = b*d;
ARITHMETIC gcd = GCD( numerator , denominator );

// because we know that GCD(e,f) is 1, this implies:
ARITHMETIC e = numerator / gcd;
ARITHMETIC f = denominator / gcd;
```